# Is there a function in python to map out the values of dates like [2011,2012,2013,204] to 2011-2014. where as [2003,2006,2007,2008] to 2003, 2006-2008

Tags: python, list, loops

Iam working on the file that has lots of dates that are in consecutive order. There are few instances where there are not in consecutive order e.g. 2004, 2007, 2008. is there a way to write python function to get the values.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Dintspan). You could get the results from the intspan module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can build a function to do group them using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) yourself, others have suggested external libraries which can probably also do this

```
>>> from itertools import count, groupby
>>> years = [2003, 2006, 2007, 2008]
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(years, key=lambda x, c=count(): x - next(c))]
[[2003], [2006, 2007, 2008]]
```

Getting the first and last elements

```
>>> [[next(g)] + list(g)[-1:] for k, g in 
     groupby(years, key=lambda x, c=count(): x-next(c))]
[[2003], [2006, 2008]]
```

**How it Works:**

[`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) gives you an iterator that gives values `0, 1, 2, 3`

So then when you have the years eg. `2003, 2006, 2007, 2008`

The key `lambda` used to group the years, takes one parameter `x` which is the `year` in this case. We also initialize a `count()` within the `lambda` which we subtract from each `year`, giving us

```
2003, 2005, 2005, 2005
```

as `count` keeps incrementing eg.

```
count = 0, 1, 2, 3, ... # as we go on
```

Which allows `groupby` to create the correct groups

The last part

```
[next(g)] + list(g)[-1:]
```

works because the groups returned by `groupby` are iterators so `next(g)` gives us the first element in the group and `list(g)` gives us the rest of the elements, of which we take a slice `[-1:]` which gives us a `list` of only the last element if it exists, otherwise just an empty `list`

Comment: it worked like champ. however, i don't understand the syntax. Can y ou please share the link to reference. i just wanted to understand code fully.

Comment: @ganeshghimire I already shared the link to the `itertools` library. I've now added an explanation of the code.